# Can DocuSign provide a username and password when sending an envelope-specific webhook?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have DocuSign running with Appian, and I am able to send documents out for signature. I'm now looking to have Appian be notified when events happen with the envelope.

For Appian to start a process, the webhook must pre-emptively provide a username and password to the process. Can this be done somewhere in eventNotification?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account-level webhooks support [Basic Authentication](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-connect-basic-authentication-support), but envelope-level EventNotifications do not.

Answer (score -1):

No passwords can be used in clear-text with DocuSign for security reasons.
You can only use access tokens.
Appian will have to use OAuth and obtain an access token to make API calls.

Comment: The q is about webhook messages, not API access

Comment: Actually, he wants to make API calls from the webhook to Appian. It's about both